# React native, Issue on Auto Focus with Samsung Galaxy SM-S120VL (Samsung Galaxy Luna)

Tags: android, react-native, qr-code, autofocus, react-native-camera

I tried to implement QR code scanning with `react-native-camera` library. It works fine for all devices but not working with a specific device. **Samsung Galaxy Luna**

**Update**

For this specific phone auto focus is not working hence not able to scan QR code properly. While on other mobiles with same configuration auto focus is working perfectly.

Library: [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you give a little bit more information about the problem.

Comment: I believe knowing which library was used would also help.

Comment: @BünyaminBennyGenel See this https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera

Comment: Have you tried to test the code with a second Samsung Galaxy Luna? You should eliminate the hardware problem possibility since the problem happens on just one phone.